# send html email that contains javascript within ios app

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c

Am trying to send an html(which javascript tags) email from my ios app. there is no errors but the javascript will not work

my code below:

```
- (IBAction)sendDirection:(id)sender {

// Email Subject
NSString *emailTitle = @"example subject";
// Email Content
NSString *messageBody = @"<html><head><script>function initialize(){document.getElementById('directions').innerHTML = 'testing';}</script></head><body onload='initialize()'></div><span id='directions'></span></body></html>";
// To address
NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"info@example.com"];

MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mc setSubject:emailTitle];
[mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:YES];
[mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

// Present mail view controller on screen
[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: what are you viewing the html in?

Comment: Javascript wont work with this type of html in MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: @connor: am using it on MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: @insane-36 : do hav an idea of wat will work, am jst trying to read the content of the javascript and send via mail

Comment: I suppose you will have to use your own server to send the email which can actually evaluate javascripts.

Comment: thanks @insane-36, thats a nice idea, let me try it

Answer (score 1):

Many email clients disable JavaScript to prevent XSS attacks and other vulnerabilities. Your best bet is to stick to plain HTML+CSS, and even then some of the more *interesting* CSS features may not be available, depending on the client.

It's hard to tell what you're trying to do with JavaScript, but it's best if you keep all programming in Objective-C and use mail composer only for HTML markup.

Comment: am trying to get google text direction and send it as email to the user

Comment: why can't you send it as a plain HTML without JavaScript?